# The meaning of the verb 'have' when a country occurs as its subject

Tags: word-usage

I'm confused about the exact meaning of 'have' in the following sentence.

> Germany has the second highest per capita beer consumption of the seven countries.

I can generally understand what the sentence means, which says that the per capita beer consumption in Germany is the second highest in the seven countries.

I guess the meaning of 'have' used here probably corresponds to the gloss 'used to say what qualities or features someone or something possess, etc.' (in Longman). But if the sense were what 'have' means here, the usage would be strange for me, especially when the word is used with a country as its subject. Can a particular amount be viewed as one of a country's qualities? Or there is other sense that 'have' actually means in the sentence?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is quite usual to assign qualities or possessions to a country.

- The USA has 50 states
- The UK has a population of 68,296,383.

Your example says that a statistic - 'the second-highest per capita beer consumption of seven countries' - *belongs* to Germany. It 'belongs' to Germany in the sense that it is *assignable* to that country.